# SQL, sum inside of case condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to learn sql query and i want to solve the following problem.

Assume the table as follow:

| id | schoolname | totalA | totalB | grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | school A | 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | school A | 5 | 5 | 2 |
| 3 | school B | 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 4 | school B | 5 | 5 | 2 |

```
Select schoolname
SUM(CASE WHEN (grade='1' ) THEN totalA ELSE 0 END) AS t1A,
SUM(CASE WHEN (grade='1' ) THEN totalB ELSE 0 END) AS t1B,
SUM(CASE WHEN (grade='2' ) THEN totalA ELSE 0 END) AS t2A,
SUM(CASE WHEN (grade='2' ) THEN totalB ELSE 0 END) AS t2B,
```

I would like to know if it is possible to add both totalA and B in one case condition.

I tried

```
Select schoolname
CASE WHEN (grade='1' ) THEN SUM(totalA+totalB) ELSE 0 END AS Grade 1,
CASE WHEN (grade='2' ) THEN SUM(totalA+totalB) ELSE 0 END AS Grade 2,
From school
Group By schoolname
```

But it give me error.

I want to achieve the following:

| schoolname | grade 1 | grade 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| School A | 10 | 10 |
| School B | 10 | 10 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible by group by query of MySQL in the same table.

For that you need to use this type of query:

```
SELECT schoolname,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (grade = 1) THEN totalA + totalB ELSE 0 END) AS grade_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (grade = 2) THEN totalA + totalB ELSE 0 END) AS grade_2
FROM school
GROUP BY schoolname
```